# Smart Filtering with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

Lets assume that i have an AR model Foo

**Foo.find** methods will return all entries from the foo table based on the criteria.. What i need is to have some kind of default criteria like country column so that if i define this somehow in AR, all my **Foo.find** methods will return entries only from that country...

How can i tell AR to use such default behaviour or set it dynamically?

Comment: I guess you're looking for scopes and default scope

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you are talking about overriding the find functionality, which is probably not that safe, but do-able.  You'll run into issues with supporting the different find formats as well. For example, how will you handle Foo.find(1) and Foo.find([1,2,3])? To do this in a safe way you should really use scopes. For example, in Rails 3 you would do the following:

```
class Foo
  scope :country, lambda{ |country| where(country: country) }
end
```

You could then use this scope anytime you make a call to query Foo. For example:

```
Foo.country('United States').where(...).all
```

If you wanted to simplify this code further because you used it a lot, you could create a function on Foo to deal with this as well:

```
class Foo
  def self.with_country
    country(current_selected_country)
  end
end
```

So that you could make find calls like this:

```
Food.with_country.all
```

By using this method you avoid having to override default ActiveRecord functionality, so your code is easier for other developers to understand and you don't have to worry about supporting a bunch of different method formats and calls.

If you do want this to be your default behavior, you can use the ActiveRecord default_scope like this:

```
class Foo
  default_scope where(country: 'United States')
end
```

This will be applied when creating a record, but not when updating a record.

Comment: many thx for the answer... but in my question i was asking how to get rid of with_country part because this will be set by default in all find methods... I am getting country from domain/subdomin part so it must be dynamically set and i should be able to call AR model find methods without using Foo.with_country all the time...

Comment: I added the default scope solution to my answer as well.